I can find and update records, but not create them using Prisma and Nextjs
My provider is sqlserver and I am connecting to an existing database. I followed the steps in the docs to connect and use npx prisma db pull to introspect.
The schema was updated successfully, and using findMany as well as updateMany works as expected. However both create, and createMany are returning an error

String or binary data would be truncated

I am trying to create a record with a 10 character description on a row that allows for a 30 character limit, so it should not be truncated.
I can see that the collation looks correct with prisma:info SQL collation changed to windows-1252 in the terminal.
Here is my model:
model TR_PHONE_TYPE {
  id                                                                        Int                      @id(map: "PK_TR_PHONE_TYPE") @default(autoincrement())
  description                                                               String                   @db.VarChar(30)
  created_by                                                                String?                  @default("[dbo].[FS_USERNAME]()", map: "DF_TR_PHONE_TYPE_created_by") @db.Char(8)
  create_dt                                                                 DateTime?                @default(now(), map: "DF_TR_PHONE_TYPE_create_dt") @db.DateTime
  last_updated_by                                                           String?                  @default("[dbo].[FS_USERNAME]()", map: "DF_TR_PHONE_TYPE_last_updated_by") @db.Char(8)
  last_update_dt                                                            DateTime                 @default(now(), map: "DF_TR_PHONE_TYPE_last_update_dt") @db.DateTime
  create_loc                                                                String?                  @default("[dbo].[FS_LOCATION]()", map: "DF_TR_PHONE_TYPE_create_loc") @db.VarChar(16)
  inactive                                                                  String                   @default("N", map: "DF_TR_PHONE_TYPE_inactive") @db.Char(1)
  control_group                                                             Int                      @default(-1, map: "DF_TR_PHONE_TYPE_control_group")
  tele_ind                                                                  String                   @default("Y", map: "DF_TR_PHONE_TYPE_tele_ind") @db.Char(1)
  de_ind                                                                    String?                  @db.Char(1)
  TR_CONTROL_GROUP                                                          TR_CONTROL_GROUP         @relation(fields: [control_group], references: [id], onUpdate: NoAction, map: "FK_TR_PHONE_TYPE_TR_CONTROL_GROUP_control_group")
  T_PHONE                                                                   T_PHONE[]
}

I am trying to create a new record as so:
await prisma.TR_PHONE_TYPE.create({
        data: {
            description: 'Banana',
        },
    })

I tried testing without autoincrement and forcibly passing a valid ID because I added in the autoincrement myself, but I got the same error in either case.
Thank you for any assistance!

You have some defaults with FS_USERNAME and FS_LOCATION that are CHAR(8) and VARCHAR(16), maybe those are the ones getting truncated? You should trace the calls that prisma makes

As @siggemannen implied, the real problem here was a lack of good error messages. No amount of logging, hitting breakpoints, or adding telemetry had been giving me any better information than the original String or binary data would be truncate error message.
Ultimately this microsoft learn article was my guiding light, and I was able to use this article to understand that I should run DBCC TRACEON(460, -1); in my sandbox database to get improved truncation errors.
Improving the quality of the error messages at the database level has unblocked me and solved my issue.
